Remote SSH keeps opening new VS Code instances
When I launch VS Code and connect to a remote (from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 22) using the Remove SSH extension, I get some problematic behaviour: VS Code launches a new instance, and new instance launches another new instance, and so on and so on. Until I close the last instance, then it stops. It would probably crash Windows if not stopped.
This also happens when I open a new Terminal within the current session.
Why is this happening?


This is probably happening because you selected Remote-SSH: Connect to Host... instead of Remote-SSH: Connect Current Window to Host... in the dropdown menu at the top of the window. You should use the former instead — this will keep the remote host connection in window you are currently in.

I tried, and no, it also happens when Connect Current Window to Host...
